# Is a view communicating with another view via a delegate a violation of MVC?

Tags: objective-c, model-view-controller, view, delegates

On the MVC paradigm, a view can only communicate with a controller, and via a blind communication (target-action or delegate/dataSource). I understand that, but is it a violation of MVC if a view communicates with another view, using a delegate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost always. The delegate of the view should never be another view. It should be a controller. The controller is the appropriate place to drive changes in the other view.

A view should almost never say something that another view would care about. A view should say to its delegate things like "I was touched." Why would another view care? It's up to the controller to say "ah, a touch here means that I should move the active focus. I should tell the current active view to let go of focus" (as an example). I view is not responsible for determining what events *mean* in the broader application, only what events *happened*, and so are very unlikely to generate messages of interest to other views.

Comment: Yep. Thats what I think is correct on the MVC model. Now imagine you have an View A and that view A has an subview (View B). B needs to talk to its superview (A). Delegation between views is the most non-violating MVC way I think of. Another way is promote this A/B structure to a Controller with two subviews. This last solution what I'm doing now to solve this conundrum. What do you think? Thank you for your response and take care!

Comment: It is appropriate for a view to be aware of its immediate subviews and superview. And it is generally appropriate for a view to act as delegate for its subviews. This improves encapsulation. The view should just avoid driving application logic; in many cases it may just pass subview delegate messages to its own delegate. But it is appropriate for views within a hierarchy to communicate about their display issues (managing their highlighting and layout for instance).

Answer (score 0):

My opinion on this is to use the observer design pattern and simply use notifications (NSNotification)

Comment: Can you give an example of a case where one view would correctly observe notifications posted by another view? View notifications should generally not be of the kind that another view should care about. If they are, the originating view is probably doing too much.

Comment: Hi there mprivat! Thank you for the response. This may raise another issue on the MVC design, since Notification Center is a way for that MODEL talk back to its CONTROLLER. So I think that using NSNotification on a VIEW (according to my understanding) is a violation of MVC, since you have delegates/datasources and target/actions to accomplish this.

Comment: Not quite. A notification isn't a way to communicate with another component. It's a way to broadcast information. Then observers are free to observe whatever they way. In MVC, the controller "controls" the view's behavior (duh) based on external actions (usually users, but can also be some other system's changes, etc...), and the view is only responsible for representing its data accurately at all time. To achieve this, it is perfectly acceptable for the view to listen to notifications representing changes in data.

Comment: Rob, an example would be for a view that represents the state of another view. The observed view would fire notifications about its state, the observing view would react accordingly. The controller has nothing to do in this case. I realize I'm reaching here, but there are cases where a view might observe another view directly without breaching the MVC pattern, because the observed view is essentially also the model of the observer view.

Answer (score -1):

I am a novice myself. But I would think that it's not. A jsp page when called could just redirect you to anothr jsp page. I have seen that happen sometime. So I guess it is in a way, a view calling another view.